# Extract subdomain or domain from url string

Tags: javascript, substring, slice

I have the following string :

```
var url = "po1.btr.en.mycompany.com";
```

I would like to extract the following subdomain **".btr.en.mycompany.com".**

How can i do this ?

Comment: You could split on the dot character, then take everything but the first and concatenate them back together with a dot.

Comment: What is the pattern of the given url?Is there any?

Comment: There are a bazillion ways to do that. What _exactly_ are the criteria of what should be removed?

Answer (score 0):

This should do what you need :)

```
var url = "po1.btr.en.mycompany.com";
var clean = url.substr(url.indexOf('.') + 1);
alert(clean);
```

Comment: `var clean = url.substr(url.indexOf('.') + 1);`. You don't need a `replace`.

Comment: Also: `alert(clean)`

Answer (score 0):

You can find the match using regex:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var link = "po1.btr.en.mycompany.com";
    var reg = /btr.*\.com/;
    window.alert(reg.exec(link));
</script>
```